# Delete cell directly below a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a script to find a value and delete both that cell and the cell directly below it. My initial thought is to use offset, but not exactly sure how.

```
Dim batch As Range

For Each batch In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If batch.Value = "Batch" Then batch.Cells.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    'Delete cell below all cells containing 'batch'
Next batch
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `Resize()`

```
Sub lskdhfdg()
    Dim batch As Range
    
    For Each batch In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If batch.Value = "Batch" Then batch.Resize(2, 1).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    Next batch
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**

only 1 line change:

```
Sub lskdhfdg2()
    Dim batch As Range
    
    For Each batch In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If InStr(batch.Value, "Batch") > 0 Then batch.Resize(2, 1).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    Next batch
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. It only works when the text in the cell is only 'Batch', however I need the code to detect if the cell **contains** 'Batch' as there is other text in the cell. How can I make this a partial match?

Comment: EDIT: I used the 'Like' operator and it deleted Batch as a partial string match successfully... now it does not delete the cell directly below cells containing the keyword, just deletes the cells with 'Batch'

Comment: @patriciajlim  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @patriciajlim  Note we still need `Resize()` to delete 2 cells

Comment: Resize is included in the code; still not deleting the cell below, unless we need it twice? Anyway here is what I am trying to achieve: In the image, delete 'Batch' followed by the number below it so that only the street and city are both still remaining. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csdn8.png

Comment: @patriciajlim  **I know what the problem is.** We need to run the loop from bottom to top rather than top to bottom............my error................I will try to fix later today..................sorry

Comment: Any luck with the script?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will do what you want:

```
For Each batch In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If batch.Value = "Batch" Then
        Range(batch, batch.Cells.Offset(1, 0)).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    End If
Next batch
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. Am looking to delete every cell below the cells that contain 'Batch', but can't get it to delete the cell directly below.